# Rails Simple Form Association Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, associations, simple-form

I am using Simple Form and the Invoicing gem, but when I try to render the form, I get "RuntimeError in InvoicingLedgerItems#new" with "Association :sender_id not found".  I want to save the primary key of the Users table (Devise gem) in the sender_id field (because the user is the sender of the invoice).  I tried using the foreign_key option in the model, but it didn't seem to have any effect.  Here's my code without using the foreign_key option.

Models:

```
class InvoicingLedgerItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_ledger_item

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :line_items, class_name: 'InvoicingLineItem', foreign_key: :ledger_item_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoicing_ledger_items
end
```

View:

```
<%= simple_form_for @invoicing_ledger_item do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :sender_id %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
  end

  create_table "invoicing_ledger_items", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.string   "type"
    t.datetime "issue_date"
    t.string   "currency",     limit: 3,                           null: false
    t.decimal  "total_amount",            precision: 20, scale: 4
    t.decimal  "tax_amount",              precision: 20, scale: 4
    t.string   "status",       limit: 20
    t.string   "identifier",   limit: 50
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "period_start"
    t.datetime "period_end"
    t.string   "uuid",         limit: 40
    t.datetime "due_date"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `InvoicingLedgerItem ` and `Sender`?

Comment: There is no relationship between InvoicingLedgerItem and Sender, because there is no Sender model.  The sender is the User, so the relationship is between InvoicingLedgerItem and User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to Make a relation with user model through foreign key 'sender_id'

**Model**

```
class InvoicingLedgerItem < ActiveRecord::Base  
  acts_as_ledger_item  
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :sender_id  
  has_many :line_items, class_name: 'InvoicingLineItem', foreign_key: :ledger_item_id  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items  
end
```

Need to make association with user as hidden field

**View:**

```
<%= simple_form_for @invoicing_ledger_item do |f| %>  
  <%= f.association :user, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => curren_user.id } %>  
  <%= f.button :submit %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that I needed f.association :user, not f.association :sender_id.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `user_id` instead of `sender_id` in the schema first.Then use `alias_attribute :user_id, :sender_id` in `InvoicingLedgerItem` model, through this helper method you can assign a new name to the field name.

For more reference visit http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html.

Comment: I thought of changing the schema, but InvoicingLedgerItem might be subclassed in the future, and the sender could sometimes not be a user. (For instance, the sender might be a company.) That is why I decided not to change the schema.